# Adding from opposite side

Tags: database-design

I have forgotten the name of a method of calculation and used in programming.

Bassically it is going from the opposite side like this:

+- 44 55 24=24-55+44

I have forgotten the way to write it down in a simple way. 
Does anyone recognise what I am talking about? If so please remind me the method name.

Kind regards,

Comment: Uhh...prefix notation?

Comment: Thanks! Indeed that was the name of it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your description of what you want  is unintelligible. A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly". Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix notation is the answer!